# Transform XML file with Java

Tags: java, xml

I want to convert one xml to another xml with the help of java code. I want to give one xml  as input file and expecting another xml file as output. How we can do this thing with help of java? can anybody give suggestion to me.

**Input.xml**

```
<Order OrderNo=”1234567890”>

 <OrderLines>

  <OrderLine PrimeLineNo=”1” SubLineNo=”1”/>

  <OrderLine PrimeLineNo=”2” SubLineNo=”1”/>

 </OrderLines>

</Order>
```

**output.xml file**  i need output this file like this

```
<Order OrderName="1234567890">

 <OrderLines MaxOrderNumbers=”2”>

  <OrderLine LineNumber="1" SubLineNumber="1"/>

  <OrderLine LineNumber ="2" SubLineNumber ="1"/>

 </OrderLines>

</Order>
```

But i have already tried the  below code with  help of java.

```
public class XmlToXml {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String xmlStr ="<Order OrderNo=\"1234567890\"><OrderLines><OrderLine PrimeLineNo=\"1\"                     SubLineNo=\"1\"/><OrderLine PrimeLineNo=\"2\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/></OrderLines></Order>";

    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);

    String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);

      System.out.println(str);
}

private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();

         System.out.println(transformer.getParameter("xmlStr"));

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        writer.append("MaxOrderNumbers");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));

        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();

        return output;

    } catch (TransformerException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder;  
    try 
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 

        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlStr ) ) );

        return doc;

    } catch (Exception e) { 

        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: hi anybody can help to me for  writing java code

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If all you are doing is changing the text of tags and attributes, not the structure of the XML file itself, then you can simply read it in as a text file and swap all instances of one string with another using Regex. The following code should get you started:

```
//read in the file one line at a time
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.xml"));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.xml");
try {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String l = "";
    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    //get next line, assign it to l, and make sure it exists. The line after the last in the file will always be null
    while((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //replace the desired substrings of each line
        if(l.contains("PrimeLineNo")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("PrimeLineNo", "LineNumber");
        }
        if(l.contains("SubLineNo")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("SubLineNo", "SubLineNumber");
        }
        //add the line to a string buffer to be written to file later
        sb.append(l + nl);
    }   

    //after we have gone through the entire input file, write it to the output file
    fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("An unknown error occurred");
}
finally {
    //ensure the streams will always close
    in.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: have you idea  about JAXB with help how  we can do this thing.

Comment: I have never used JAXB, so I'm afraid I can't help you there

Comment: Well what is not working about it? I just threw it together, I didn't actually run and test it. Is it not compiling, or throwing errors? Or simply not producing the correct output?

Comment: this  particular line  showing  error   fos.write(sb.toString());

Comment: i was tried for chaining  this  line into  typecasting but time its  also  not  working

Comment: Yup, I think I figured it out, and I updated my answer. The output stream needs bytes to write, and we were giving it a String. I added '.getBytes()' which should do the trick

Comment: but it is not adding  MaxOrderNumbers in that  xml file

Comment: Hi cjbrooks but still  it not  giving  MaxOrderNumbers how  we can get this  attribute in that xml.

Comment: hey Cjbrooks  still it is  not giving have you idea about this?

Comment: hi can anybody  suggestion to me for  correcting the   above code

Comment: Any solution using text matching is going to be wrong. It might work 99.9% of the time, but it will still be wrong. For example, this attempt fails if strings such as "PrimeLineNo" occur in the content, rather than as attribute names. Sooner or later you will encounter an input document on which it gives the wrong answer. When processing XML, always use a real XML parser. We see hundreds of problems on StackOverflow that are caused by people trying to process XML without parsing it properly.

Comment: then  how  we can do  with help of XMl Parsing have  you idea  about that Michael Kay

Answer (score 2):

The way to tackle this is to define the transformation rules in XSLT.

You need one rule that copies things unchanged, by default:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you need further rules to define the changes you want to make:

```
<xsl:template match="@OrderNo">
 <xsl:attribute name="OrderName"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

and similarly for the other renaming rules, plus

```
<xsl:template match="OrderLines">
 <OrderLines MaxOrderLines="{count(*)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
 </OrderLines>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, having assembled these rules into a stylesheet, you can run the transformation from your Java code, using code very similar to what you have already done:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Templates t = tf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new File("stylesheet.xsl")));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.newTransformer().transform(
 new StreamSource(new File("input.xml")), 
 new StreamResult(writer));
```

Comment: No, not without writing an introductory tutorial on XSLT. But that already exists, many times over.

Comment: I deliberately don't write finished working code for people (except paying clients). I try to point you in the right direction so you can learn how to write it yourself. If you can't get it to work, feel free to raise a new question. Take care to say exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.

Comment: P.S. Writing with correct spelling and grammar is a basic courtesy and shows evidence of professionalism.

Comment: I want to be xml validation with help java code   http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=I+want+to+be+xml+validation+with+help+java+code